# RHEL 6.x image for OpenStack

Tags: openstack, rhel6

I am looking for a RHEL 6.x image to upload as an image to our Openstack System, similar to what Rackspace (https://github.com/rackerjoe/oz-image-build) provides, however they only go up to 5.6.
The idea is to have an image that supports the instance meta data server and ssh injects.

Googling didnt help much.

Cheers
Jannis

Comment: found these two useful(?) links: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/CreatingRHELImages and http://docs.openstack.org/essex/openstack-compute/starter/content/CentOS-de1592.html  Together that's probably a huge leg up on 6.x imaging.

Comment: might find better luck asking in server fault?